# LinearLayout below dynamic RecyclerView listview

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview-layout

I have a Dynamic list and the static linear layout below last item. When list is empty the `LinearLayout` is on the top of the page.

Whenever I have added element into the list the `LinearLayout` is moving below the last item of the list. When the list became long the static `LinearLayout` should be stay at the end of the screen. I have draw some examples for better understanding.

[image]

But whenever ive added 7 element, my linear layout is hiding below list.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:id="@+id/group_manage_list_view"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/group_manage_list_view"
          >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_white_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/headline_grey"
                android:id="@+id/create_group_button_click"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_group"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
               />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `android:layout_weight` to achieve this but you have to maintain **visibility** of your `recycleview` and `linearlayout` below that, say if array size is greater than zero than make it visible else not and vice-versa

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/group_manage_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/create_group_button_click"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="add_group" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmm is this approach will work when I have for example 2 items in the list? When I check the list size and make the listView visible it took 1.8 space on the screen and the linear layout goes at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes, expiredmind. When list has data it will show on screen and linearlayout will be at bottom and if not than will show only linearlayout and your issue is solved.

Comment: thats not the issue, this layout handle only two situation, when the list is empty or list is more than  for example 6 elements (according to my drawings in question). When the list have 3 elements, the linear layout should be directly below the last item, not on the bottom of the screen. Sorry for my, messy explanation, but I hope that you understand my issue

Comment: @Expiredmind i will check this issue once again and will update my answer

Comment: Nope, I used Amrish Kakadiya approach, because he implement the closest solution of my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use **`NestedScrollView`**, here is sample code. hope this may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Seomthing" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This approach almost work. The Linear Layout does not hide when the list is bigger, but unfortunately is not always visible on the screen (for example if I have 7 items i must scroll down to see the Linear Layout)

Comment: Remove `nestedScrollView` then make `RecyclerView` height `match_parent` and give `layout_weight=1`

Comment: `layout_weight=1` in `RecyclerView` make the `LinearLayout` always on the bottom of the screen